# Why do I get FileNotFoundException with slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm a spring and maven newbie, and I can't make my project work... I started a new Maven project with a webapp archetype, and got it working, even with some spring security. But now I included the hibernate dependencies at maven and no matter if I keep them or delete them from pom.xml I get:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

```
Type Exception Report

Message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse-workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\prueba6\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

I get the following errors at the console:

```
Sep 21, 2018 5:22:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext backgroundProcess
WARNING: Exception processing loader [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/prueba6]]] background process
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse-workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\prueba6\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.modified(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:708)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:287)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1368)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipse-workspace3\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\prueba6\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:164)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
    ... 14 more
```

The content of my pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>



</project>
```

I already tried to include slf4j dependency with a given version at pom.xml and no success. I read that sometimes some dependencies conflict using different slf4j versions, but I don't know how to check that! :( I guess I made a mistake that has nothing to do with hibernate, but I'm not able to find out where...

Comment: Try selecting the project in the Package Explorer pane, right-click, Refresh.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you need the .jar file which you can [get it here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1). Also, check if you already have a org.slf4j.jar anywhere in your project

Comment: Umm why did you import anything from Eclipse dependencies ?

Comment: `mvn clean package`

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me: 
- Stop Tomcat.
- Right click on Tomcat /Clean.
- Right click on Tomcat /Clean Tomcat work directory.
- Add the .war to Tomcat & start it.